# How to get focused group name using Skype4COM API in C#

Tags: c#, .net, skype4com

I am using .NET 4.0 on a Win7 64bit machine.
I am trying to get the group name when I "focus" on a group chat in Skype. When I am focusing on a group chat, I receive in ContactsFocused(string Username) callback is an empty string for Username. The callback is executed but with an empty param.
The code I wrote:

```
m_skype = new Skype();
....
 m_skype.ContactsFocused += Skype_ContactsFocused;
....
 private void Skype_ContactsFocused(string Username)
 {
        //Console.WriteLine("Skype_ContactsFocused is {0}", Username);
 }
```

When focusing a single contact this code works fine, I get a notification in Skype_ContactFocused callback with the correct name as the parameter, but on group chat this name is empty.
My question is is there a way to get the "focused" group name?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really late response, but here's how you get the current focused group name: instead of reading out Username, you must read out `m_skype.ActiveChats[1].Topic`.  You can also read out `m_skype.ActiveChats[1].FriendlyName` if you prefer to see your friends' screen name versus their login usernames. Here's how your interrupt should look like:

```
private static void Skype_ContactsFocused(string Username)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("Skype_ContactsFocused is {0}", Username);
    Console.WriteLine("Skype_ContatsFocused is " + ((m_skype.ActiveChats[1].Topic != "") ? m_skype.ActiveChats[1].Topic : m_skype.ActiveChats[1].FriendlyName));
}
```

Please note that attempting to focus a chat where the name is the default (a list of names is the topic), the program might not register it correctly.  This also occurs if there are chats with the same topic name.

I hope this is still of some use for you even though it's been over a year :-)